# WCF Server waiting for return before proceeding

Tags: wcf

Here is what I would like to do. 
1. Service hosted in WCF
2. Client calls asking for a payload of messages
3. Service returns payload of messages and waits for client to respond 
 3.A. Client returns 200 (OK) status or something confirming messages received. 
 3.B. Client returns bad error status stating to not delete the messages on server. 
4. Depending on 3.A or 3.B Service will take appropriate action. 

I would like to do this by doing something like extending IDispatcher and writing extension methods. VS creating another service and having the client call that service to signal which messages it received. Unless that's best practices.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If acting on HTTP status codes is a requirement then WCF is probably not what you want to use. WCF was created to be able to write transport independent code so the bindings could be changed purely through configuration; no code changes required. The HTTP request handling is buried so deeply into HTTP-based bindings that you're better off using something like the [OpenRasta framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenRasta) to implement your HTTP (REST) style service. It is a very HTTP request aware framework.

Otherwise, look at this [wsDualHttpBinding intro](http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx) to accomplish something similar through the application API level.